# DB2 SQL Split Record by Delimiter if exists

Tags: sql, db2

I would like to return the portion of a string *BEFORE* a delimiter (in this case, a hyphen). What I find is that DB2 is throwing an error because there's an inconsistency in the values of the column where some records have a hyphen meanwhile others do not. So, I'd like to return the string before hyphen if it exists, otherwise just return the string as is.

Example shown with COLUMN1 below:

| ID | COLUMN1 |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | ASHJE-JFE |
| 2 | QER-SK |
| 3 | KSETK |
| 4 | SDJ-EJLF |

I wrote the following query to return the string prior/before '-' but, I get the following error:

> The statement was not executed because a numeric argument of a scalar
> function is out of range.

I believe this is because there are records where a hyphen does not exist...

```
select distinct column1, locate('-',column1), substr(column1,1, (locate('-',column1) - 1)) from db2.table
where column1 is not null
fetch first 25 rows only
with ur
```

Does anyone know how to accomplish something similar but return the string as is when a hyphen does not exist? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You may use the following expression:

```
SUBSTR (COLUMN1, 1, COALESCE (NULLIF (LOCATE ('-', COLUMN1), 0) - 1, LENGTH (COLUMN1)))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `CASE` statement to search for the hyphen along with a `LIKE` operator and `%` wildcards.

```
SELECT ID, column1,
CASE WHEN column1 LIKE '%-%'
THEN substr(column1,1,locate('-',column1)-1)
ELSE column1 
END AS column2
FROM fileName
WHERE column1 IS NOT NULL
FETCH FIRST 25 ROWS ONLY
```

See [Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=db2_11.1&fiddle=fbd3c378e466b802bd3081f6fb4b5b1e)

Result:

| ID | COLUMN1 | COLUMN2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | ASHJE-JFE | ASHJE |
| 2 | QER-SK | QER |
| 3 | KSETK | KSETK |
| 4 | SDJ-EJLF | SDJ |